# Multiple overlapping actors trigger event in Unreal Engine 4 editor

Tags: events, triggers, overlap, eventtrigger, unreal-engine4

Is it possible to trigger an event only when there are *multiple* actors in the trigger volume? 
For example a background music starts playing only if there are two specifically tagged actors placed at a trigger volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to count the number of overlapping actors somewhere. I think the simplest solution is to create your own "trigger volume" by adding a collision box to a new actor and listening to the "begin overlap" and "end overlap" events.

Once your actor has counted enough overlaps you can start your background music or whatever it is that you want to do.